# Rails 4 query sorting by month and year

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble with the best way to do this but essentially I have a blog where I want to show an archive of the month and year of all the published blogs.  Clicking a link "May 2012" will bring you to all the blogs written in between that month on the same year (for example: May 5th 2012, May 20th 2012...).  Is there a way to get all the records within the same month of the same year just using created_at and passing params of the numerical month and year?  Is there a better way to do this overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this in your controller:

```
month = Date.new(params[:year], params[:month])
@entries = Blog.where(created_at: month.all_month)
```

The `#all_month` method will create a Range containing the beginning and end of the month, and passing a Range in the where clause makes a BETWEEN query for the date.

Comment: Is `all_month` new in Rails 4.1?

Comment: Just in rails 4.1.4 and it works, most concise answer

Comment: It's in the `Time` class in 3.2 and 4.0, so maybe it moved around a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that in Rails, e.g for all blogs in May 2014:

```
time = DateTime.new(2014,5)
blogs = Blog.where("created_at >= ? and created_at <= ? ", time.beginning_of_month, time.end_of_month)
```

Comment: That should probably be `BETWEEN ? AND ?` since I think you're skipping the last day here with that `<` comparison.